# How can I get only parent terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Is there any way to get only parent terms from custom taxonomy or category?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, just pass in the parent parameter to `get_terms` when you call it, as Michael pointed out.

Since WP 4.5 this is the recommend usage:

```
$myterms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name', 'parent' => 0 ) );
```

Prior to WP 4.5 this was the default usage:

```
$myterms = get_terms( 'taxonomy_name_here', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
```

Will return all terms that have a parent value of `0`, ie. top level terms.

Comment: It returns empty array for custom taxonomies :(

Comment: Are the terms in that taxonomy associated with a post(or custom type)? If not, you'll need to pass along the `hide_empty` parameter, setting that to `0` also, so you're able to see terms currently not used.

Comment: Note that this will only get parent level 1 , the "mother" term. To retrieve all ancestors, use `get_ancestors(TERM_ID, TAXONOMY, 'taxonomy')` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/

Answer (score 2):

use the 'parent' parameter:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

or

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Answer (score 2):

for woocommerce email templates use the following:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id , 'product_cat');
    if($terms) {
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $term = get_term_by("id", $term->parent, "product_cat");
            if ($term->parent > 0) {
                $term = get_term_by("id", $term->parent, "product_cat");
            }
            $cat_obj = get_term($term->term_id, 'product_cat');
            $cat_name = $cat_obj->name;
        }
    }
echo '<br />('. $cat_name . ')';
```

Comment: please add some explanation, on how your code could solve the question. OP didn't make a question about woocommerce email templates.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $archive_cats= get_terms( 'archivecat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0&parent=0' );
```

Comment: How is this different than the (already accepted) answer proposed more than two years ago?

Comment: did you see comments on the (already accepted) answer ?
if no more answers are not useful why the question still opened ?!

Comment: There was a single query with regard to terms not showing up, that was unrelated to the original question, i addressed that issue in a reply comment(as it had no bearing on the validity or correctness of the answer already provided).

Comment: Please address that in an edit. Explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

For this demonstration, we will assume that we have a taxonomy called "Books".
And we might have a hierarchy of:

```
Fiction (id: 699)
 - This is a Fiction Story.
Non-Fiction
 - Title of Non-fiction
Fantasy
  -  ...
```

We want to get the parent term of the taxonomy "Books" of the current post.

```
/* Get the Parent Taxonomy Term Name by post Id */

function get_parent_term_by_post_id($taxname, $taxid=null){

if(isset($taxid)):

    //Get by term Id passed in function
    $parent_tax = get_term_by('id', $taxid, $taxname);

    return $parent_tax ->name; //use name, slug, or id

else:

     //Get by PostId of current page
     $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), $taxname);

     $tax_parent_id = $terms[0]->parent;

     if($tax_parent_id == 0):
      $tax_parent_id = $terms[0]->parent; //get the next parent ID
     endif; 

     $parent_tax = get_term_by('id', $tax_parent_id , $taxname);

     return $parent_tax ->name; //use name, slug, or id

endif;

}
```

Then you just run on you template  like this:

```
//enter custom tax name. will grab by post id 
echo get_parent_term_name_by_post_id('books'); //returns Fiction
```

or

```
//by term ID 
echo get_parent_term_name_by_post_id('books', 699); //returns Fiction
```