# make a dropdown custom field with 'cities' list in it

Tags: custom-field, dropdown

I am developing a website for real estates. I was wondering that how can I add a dropdown to my custom forms (theme my login plugin) for cities states etc. The basic point is that I dont want to add new tables in the database. I want to achieve this without that.

Thanks

Comment: Many real estate themes use custom taxonomy to list locations in their theme, you can use that too

Comment: @Mamaduka: Thanks. Can I get some in-depth example, I am newbie in the world of wordpress :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register custom taxonomy like so:

```
<?php
// Register custom taxonomy for locations
function mamaduka_register_taxonomy_location() {
    register_taxonomy( 'location', array( 'post' ), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Locations',
        'public' => true,
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'mamaduka_register_taxonomy_location' );
?>
```

for more information about custom taxonomy see Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: That was a kind reply and thanks for that. One more thing, I will be doing it like: 1) add cities first and then 2) add locations of each city. So it will be like hierarchy. How can I get only the parent values (i.e. cities) in one place of custom theme and then child values (i.e. locations) in the other?

Comment: and I did it on my own. Thanks Mamaduka for the guidance. Mamaduka please correct me if I am wrong with my approach. A little more googling lead me to these functions: get_terms (to get the parents of my custom taxonomy i.e cities), get_term_children (to get the children id of each term in an array) and finally get_term_by (to get the childrens of each parent of my taxonomy i.e locations).

Comment: You're welcome. I had similar question so you can see here how to get only parent terms - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24582/how-can-i-get-only-parent-terms, your approach is right, see Coxed page for get_term_children there great basic example