# prevent sub categories to show up

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

i created filterable portfolio using this tutorial

*http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-wordpress-and-jquery/*

everything working well , but it grab the sub tags and its post  also not only the main tags . how i can stop this issue ?

```
        <?php
             $terms = get_terms("tagportifolio");
             $count = count($terms);
             echo '<ul id="portfolio-filter">';
                echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';
             if ( $count > 0 ){

                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                        $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                        $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                        echo '<li><a href="#'.$termname.'" title="" rel="'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
                    }
             }
             echo "</ul>";
        ?>
        <?php 
            $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
            $count =0;
        ?>

        <div id="portfolio-wrapper">
            <ul id="portfolio-list">

            <?php if ( $loop ) : 

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tagportifolio' );

                    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                        $links = array();

                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
                        {
                            $links[] = $term->name;
                        }
                        $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links); 
                        $tax = join( " ", $links );     
                    else :  
                        $tax = '';  
                    endif;
                    ?>

                    <?php $infos = get_post_custom_values('_url'); ?>

                    <li class="portfolio-item <?php echo strtolower($tax); ?> all">
                        <div class="thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(215, 215) ); ?></a></div>
                        <div class="projectcontent">
                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <p class="excerpt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></a></p>
                        <p class="links"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">More Details &rarr;</a></p>

                        </div>
                    </li>

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                <li class="error-not-found">Sorry, no portfolio entries for while.</li>

            <?php endif; ?>


            </ul>

            <div class="clearboth"></div>

        </div> <!-- end #portfolio-wrapper-->


        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
                jQuery("#portfolio-list").filterable();
            });
        </script>


                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            </div><!-- #post -->
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only the parent terms you have to use the argument [parent](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Possible_Arguments) and set **lvl 0**. 
**From codex:**

> If 0 is passed, only top-level terms are returned. Default is an empty
>   string.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'tagportifolio', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
```

See another question and answer here: [How can I get only parent terms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24582/how-can-i-get-only-parent-terms)

Comment: http://www.integritycorp.org/study/?page_id=34#all still showing the sub tags :(

Answer (score 0):

i succeed to hide from the navigation using this loop

```
<?php
$args = array('hide_empty'=>false,'parent'=>0);
$terms = get_terms("tagportifolio", $args );
$count = count($terms);
echo '<ul id="portfolio-filter">';
echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';
if ( $count > 0 ){

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $termname = strtolower($term->name);
        $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
        echo '<li><a href="#'.$termname.'" title="" rel="'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
<?php 
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
$count =0;
?>
```

but still working on the posts query