# Loop to display ONLY custom taxonomy parent information

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to display only the top level categories from a custom post type taxonomy I've created... product-category.

I'm hoping to pull the following data into a loop:

- Category title (the_title())
- Category description (the_archive_description())
- Permalink (the_permalink())
- Thumbnail (custom field... the_field(category_thumbnail))

Could somebody point me in the right direction please.

Here's my loop:

```
<?php
                $loop = new WP_Query();
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    $myterms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name', 'parent' => 0 ) );
                    foreach( wp_get_post_terms() as $term ) { ?>
                        <div class="col-eq-height col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                            <div class="product">
                                <div id="thumbnail">
                                    <?php the_field('product_category_thumbnail'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div id="content">
                                    <p id="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php }
                endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has already been answered perfectly in [How can I get only parent terms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24582/how-can-i-get-only-parent-terms).

The solution is to set `'parent' => 0` when querying terms with `get_terms()` or `WP_Term_Query`. The example from that question looked like this:

```
$myterms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name', 'parent' => 0 ) );
```

You can easily loop over the result and in it retrieve the fields you mentioned.

Hope that helps! If you need more guidance, please let me know and I can look into expanding my answer a bit.

Comment: Where would I exactly add the $myterms to the loop? Please see the code snippet I added to my answer.

Comment: Hmm maybe I misunderstood you. Your code loops through custom posts of the "products" type. Now you want to show all the categories of a product (the "product-category" taxonomy) inside that loop, but only the parent ones?

Comment: Yes, only showing the top level (parent) categories. And then just that category information. When I refer to category, I mean the custom taxonomy created for my Products CPT.

Comment: any ideas mate?

Comment: Have you tried using `wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product-category', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );`?

Comment: I can try, but where would I put that into my loop? Thanks

Comment: Anywhere between `<div class="col-eq-height col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:30px;">`. It would look like this: `foreach( wp_get_post_terms() as $term ) { …print term info here… }`

Comment: See my updated.